# vec4 for vec3 multiplication while calculating the specular value

Tags: opengl, glsl, lighting

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/directional-lights-ii/) to calculate the specular color of a vertex.

I use OpenGL 2.1 with GLSL version 120.

This is the formula that I apply:

> spec= (R*eye)^s * Ls * Lm

With:

> L= direction vector light-vertex;
>   N= vector normal;
>   eye= direction vector vertex-eye;
>   R= -2N * (L*N) + L;

Now the problem is that following this way I need to multiply a vec3 for a vec4.

This is what I tried to do:

```
vec4 L= normalize(gl_LightSource[0].position - gl_Position);
vec3 N= normalize (gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
vec4 eye= normalize(-gl_Position);
vec4 R= -2.0*N*(L*N)+L;  // Syntax error: N is a vec3
vec4 spec= (R*eye)* gl_LightSource[0].specular;
```

I wouldn't get a vec3 result when calculating the specular value, this value I would be ignoring the alpha value. How do I go around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be a `vec3` because the 4th component of the [homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) is only used for 3D transformations. If you use them for *eg.* dot products, they will likely pollute the final result.

Speaking of dot products, `R*eye` is most probably wrong; you want `dot(R,eye)` instead.

Also, the dot product should be saturated to avoid negative values.

This code should work better:

```
vec3 L = normalize(gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz - gl_Position.xyz);
vec3 N = normalize((gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal).xyz);
vec3 eye = normalize(-gl_Position.xyz);
vec3 R = -2.0 * N * max(dot(L, N), 0.0) + L;
vec3 spec = max(dot(R, eye), 0.0) * gl_LightSource[0].specular.rgb;
```

Finally, the specular power (sometimes called `shininess`) should be applied to `dot(R, eye)` before being multiplied by the specular colour, so something like this:

```
vec3 spec = pow(max(dot(R, eye), 0.0), shininess)
          * gl_LightSource[0].specular.rgb;
```

Comment: This was I'm missing the alpha value, may I just set it to 1.0? Like this: gl_FragColor+= vec4(spec,1.0); ?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Usually the alpha value does not come from the same light calculations as the colour value. You can certainly set it to 1.0 if your object is supposed to be opaque.